# Firebase database android studio crashing on pulling data from server

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have looked around for a solution for this, but nothing I have found has solved my issue.

I have a firebase realtime database with data stored in it that I send from my mobile application. 
The database has a child of the "bound_device" from my global settings. Then this child has a child per entry. This child has the data within it, these are all strings.

Upon running my pull code(see below) I get a crash stating `t1_string = data.child("T1_Data_string").getValue().toString();` is null.

However, it does exist within the actual database. Therefore, I presume I am doing something incorrect.
My code is as follows:

```java
public static DatabaseReference mDatareff_User;
```

Storage code:

```java
mDatareff_User = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(global_settings.Get_Bound_device());//Get the reference of the device
        mDatareff_User.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    t1_string = data.child("T1_Data_string").getValue().toString();
                    t2_string = data.child("T2_Data_string").getValue().toString();
                    t3_string = data.child("T3_Data_string").getValue().toString();
                    t4_string = data.child("T4_Data_string").getValue().toString();
                    pd_string = data.child("Pdiff_Data_string").getValue().toString();
                    time_string = data.child("Time_string").getValue().toString();
                    boolean result = BLE_DB.addData_Downloaded(t1_string,t2_string,t3_string,t4_string,pd_string,time_string);//Add data
                    if (result == true) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "data_changes: Added data correctly");}
                    if (result == false) {Log.d(TAG, "data_changes: did not add data correctly");}//false
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Note I am storing this data to an internal SQL database.

Below is a screen shot of the database entries within the console:
Also the `global_settings.Get_Bound_device()` is the same as the first child.
[image]

Below is an image of the bound device as a string to compare.

[image]

Comment: The error is suggesting the the data you're looking for is actually not present.  Your code should check for that.

Comment: I agree that is what is is suggesting however, I can view it in the firebase database in the console. So I presume it is the way in which I pull it is incorrect.

Comment: Since we can't also see the data, we don't know for sure what's going wrong. I suggest adding a screenshot so we can connect the dots.

Comment: adding you db screenshot and showing value of "global_settings.Get_Bound_device()" can help other to find out issue.

Comment: I have updated my post to include the screenshot of the data.

Comment: not sure about your reference to db as its not complete screenshot but can you see the keys name in your reference and in code, they are change, capital letters make difference.

Comment: @HaiderSaleem I can't believe it was such a simple fix that solve it thank you!  Please post as an answer so I can approve it.

Comment: Also @Doug Stevenson thanks for you assistance as well.

Comment: @ThomasMorris glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capital letters make difference.
Replace

```
                t1_string = data.child("T1_Data_string").getValue().toString();
```

with

```
                t1_string = data.child("t1_Data_string").getValue().toString();
```

same for other.